# CanOpen: Is there a communication profile for "emergency object" "manufacturer-specific error field"?

Tags: can-bus, canopen

I need to read data in byte 3-7 of the Emergency object.

Picture below, byte 2 is the standardized CanOpen error register available in communication profile `0x1001h` (I am able to read this). I need the info in the "manufacturer-specific error field" (byte3-7).

[image]
[image]

---

This following picture is from the manufacturer datasheet:

[image]

I tried reading the communication profiles `0x1002h` & `0x1003h` but the information was not there.

(yes I am able to read the raw value 0x80+NID with a can parser, but I would like to know if it is available via a CanOpen communication profile)

Comment: As far as I can remember, this info isn't stored in any standardized location in the OD. Upon generating an EMCY, the device is supposed to set the error type in 1001h. For as long as there's an error there, the node may not enter operational state. When the error is cleared, the node should send out a new EMCY message with everything set to zero.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for sharing your recollection. Your statement is also what I was afraid of. Strange that the manufacturer chose to share the sensor state in this custom byte area.

Comment: Not strange at all. Why wouldn't you want to be updated about errors in real-time?

Comment: I was just thinking that it would perhaps better to have the custom sensor status message in a PDO, so it complies with the CanOpen object directory. But yes the data itself is valuable, that's why I want to read it :)

Comment: I suppose you could configure a RPDO with the same COBID as the EMCY message and have it automatically store this info that way. If that's CANopen compliant, I'm not sure, but it will likely work in practice. (Might need to support dynamic PDO mapping)

Comment: We are using additonal status objects in the dictionary which can be read via SDO to get more information about the device status. The CANopen standard is most of the time not detailed enough for us.

Answer (score 0):

The data I needed was in 1003h. I did not just know how to interpret the data. Index 0 (U8) is a counter of number of errors. index 1 - FF (U32) is error messages, where index 1 is the newest message and subsequent indexes are older messages. The two lower bytes of the message was 0x80+NID: Byte0-1, while the two upper bytes was 0x80+NID: Byte3-4.